# How to convert int into comma separated string in php?

Tags: php

I want to convert int into comma separated string in php.
for example,

`100000` into `"1,00,000".`

Comment: Details about where the comma's should be placed are missing, and the example does not make things clear.

Comment: @Luuk erm, suppose I want to place comma's after 3 digits from the left, and then 2 digits onwards. then? ex: 1,00,00,000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use number_format

```php
$number=number_format(100000);

$echo $number; //output 100,000
```

or

```php
$number=number_format(100000);
$newNumber=sprintf('"%s"',$number);  

echo $newNumber ;  //output "100,000"
```

Comment: Did does not work as commented "I want to place comma's after 3 digits from the left, and then 2 digits onwards"

Comment: solved ...no problem

Comment: done! @dılo sürücü

Comment: This `echo number_format(100000000);` returns `100,000,000` which does not seem to be your request?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `number_format()` function

```
<?php

$number = '100000.457888';

echo number_format($number, 0); // returns 100,000
echo number_format($number, 1); // returns 100,000.5
echo number_format($number, 2); // returns 100,000.46
echo number_format($number, 3); // returns 100,000.458
echo number_format($number, 4); // returns 100,000.4579
```